# delete all records in mongoDB Spring application using CURL

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I'm Working with one of Spring's tutorials on integrating Spring with Mongo DB.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/

I simply want to be able to delete multiple records using CURL.

something like

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/people/
```

The tutorial shows how to delete a specific record but not multiple records. Fairly new with working with CURL as well..Pretty sure I'm missing something simple, thanks.
FYI the method to delete a single record would be

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/people/53149b8e3004990b1af9f229
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should run this

```
mongo <dbname> --eval "db.people.drop()"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the example project you linked, Spring Boot automatically wires a [RepositoryEntityController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java), that exposes basically two URIs:

```
http://localhost:8080/people/
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/people/{id}
```

where `{id}` is a specific person's id.

It also provides some methods and binds them with one of the URIs above. For example, there is the `getCollectionResource` method, that "listens to" `http://localhost:8080/people/`, so you can run

```
curl http://localhost:8080/people/
```

and get a list of the people saved in your database.

The method `deleteItemResource` on the other hand, "listens to" `http://localhost:8080/people/{id}`, so the specific [controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) does not provide the functionality of simultaneously deleting all person entities.

But you can always write your own controller and provide your custom functionality. The trivial code below will do the work (but will not include all the other methods of course):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository people;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteAll() {
        people.deleteAll();
    }

}
```